# How can I test multiple device screen densities for web?

Tags: html, css, mobile

Let's say I want to build a web application for Phonegap.

I can design it as much as I can on my pc screen, but since there are a lot of different screen densities on mobile devices and we use mostly px units on HTML/CSS, the elements' sizes may vary a lot from one device to another...

Since I don't have all those physical devices, is there another way I can test it? Using somekind of browser addon, app or online tool?

Thank you

Comment: Related: [A pixel is not a pixel is not a pixel](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)

Comment: Personally, I like the Chrome emulation of User Agent and Device metrics when I only want to test Html/Css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mobile phone emulator

http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/

select device where you test and then open your site link,

here is another good simulator

http://transmog.net/iphone-simulator/

```
i use 2nd one to test my site and app....
```

Comment: the second link won't work here, but the first one should do it fine

Comment: Its work fine here, may be link is restrict in your local connection... If you have dynamic IP so restrart your Connection or P.C then visit again,, if problem solve, so its ok, other wise, use first link... :)